# How to implement SOAP Endpoints that receive SOAP XML (SAAJ?) Instead of generated objects using CXF

Tags: java, soap, apache-camel, cxf, saaj

We have currently implemented **SOAP endpoints with CXF** (Spring Boot). In accordance with the contract-first approach, we provide a WSDL, generate Java objects, and services from it (cxf-codegen-plugin) and finally implement the service interface.

This is all very nice and simple, but **we only need the SOAP XML or the corresponding DOM tree**. Not only is the conversion to Java objects unnecessary, we also have to convert them back to XML and **lose some information from the original XML**.

As far as I understand is **SAAJ** (SOAP with Attachments API for Java) exactly right here, or am I missing something? At most all resources about SAAJ are **quite old** and "low level". I cannot find good resources for that kind of approach.

In addition, we want to implement new services as microservices soon and are currently reviewing **Quarkus** and **Apache Camel**. However, I cannot find a (simple) way to create corresponding endpoints from the WSDLs, via which we then receive the SOAP message as plain XML / DOM tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jax-ws, message-level access can be accomplished on the server side using web service Provider-based endpoints, and on the client side using Dispatch clients.

A web service Provider-based endpoint offers a dynamic alternative to the Java service endpoint interface (SEI)-based endpoint. Unlike the SEI-based endpoint that abstracts the details of converting between Java objects and their XML representation, the Provider interface enables you to access the content directly at the XML message level—without the JAXB binding. web service Provider-based endpoints can be implemented synchronously or asynchronously using the javax.xml.ws.Provider or com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.AsyncProvider interfaces, respectively.

See https://cxf.apache.org/docs/provider-services.html for details

Comment: Thanks! Obviously I haven't read the CXF documentation carefully enough. Now I just have to figure out how to use the whole thing in Quarkus ... currently my endpoint is currently not successfully published ...